# Modulus operation with BigInteger returning 0

Tags: c#, math, biginteger

I'm attempting to calculate a modulus using 2 BigIntegers in C#.

Here's the method in question:

```
    static List<int> Get(BigInteger possibleColours, BigInteger length, BigInteger i)
    {
        List<int> ret = new List<int>();
        BigInteger sizes = 1;


        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            BigInteger index = (i/sizes) % possibleColours;

            ret.Add((int)index);
            sizes *= possibleColours;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

This line is where the problem is:

```
BigInteger index = (i/sizes) % possibleColours;
```

The divide operation seems to work fine, but the modulus always seems to set index to 0, no matter which way I break it up, i.e. to do one operation per line.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can provide some set of values that you think should work in your case ?

Comment: sure, for my test case I have:

possibleColours: 65536, length: 100, i: 20

Comment: the point is that there is no apparent reasons your code shouldn't work, so I expect that this is a normal behavior. what are `i` and `sizes` in this case so?

Comment: Btw, why are you using BigInteger for values like 65536 and 20?

Comment: Well, actually my i is (65536^100)/2, which leaves me with all zeroes at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following data samples you provide:

```
possibleColours: 65536,  
i: 20
```

You increment `sizes` here:

```
sizes *= possibleColours;
```

so already on second iteration you have (applying sample data provided in place):

```
                    i   sizes   possibleColours
BigInteger index = (20/65536) % 65536;
```

where `20/65536 == 0` as you devide `integers`, so result of devision is also `integer` itself.

After we get:

`BigInteger index = 0 % 65536;`, so `index==0`.

That means after first iteration you will get always `0`, what your are experiencing actually.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I adapted the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269598/logic-to-select-a-specific-set-from-cartesian-set/22269999), hoping that instead of selecting a character, I could select a number from possibleColours.

Answer (score 2):

Both `i` and `sizes` are BigInteger. So whenever `sizes>i`, `(i/sizes)==0` because it's an integer division. That could be the problem.