# Select subset of test cases from all possible combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing

Let's say I'm writing a lifespan prediction calculator that takes in ~40 inputs:

```py
sex = ['Male', 'Female']
smoking_status = [True, False]
...
```

Eventually, there will be trillions of possible test cases that can be exposed using `itertools` but these are computed by gradually adjusting each field from left to right:

```py
for test_case in itertools.product(sex, smoking_status):
    assert(myfunc(test_case) = trueval(test_case)
```

Output (*not* randomized):

```py
['Male', True]
['Male', False]
['Female', True]
['Female', False]
```

How can I randomly select `N=1000` test cases from all possible combinations?

**Edit:**
Constraint #1: As I am concerned over the health and wellbeing of my laptop, I am adding a constraint where I cannot generate a list containing hundreds of trillions of elements and then randomly select a subset of it :)

Comment: This is a follow up question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401307/python-finding-inputs-of-every-possible-test-case/71401561?noredirect=1#comment126251681_71401561 which calculated ALL possible combinations rather than a random subset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select 50 items from list at random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511349/select-50-items-from-list-at-random)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for researching. That question has a list that has already been generated, but I want to avoid generating a list as it would have trillions of indexes in my case

Comment: You should clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was eventually storing all variables in a dictionary where keys are the variable names and values are a list of all possible values

I then looped through each item, (Pseudo-code:) `[k:v[randint(0, len(v))] for k, v in mydict.items()]` and used the random integer function to randomly choose an index

NOTE: This does not account for overlap; it is possible to produce 2 identical test cases but it's acceptable for me as there are trillions of possible test cases